# How to measure added voltage to my input?

Tags: amplifier

I want to measure the voltage I'm adding to my input signal to my amplifier. My setup looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZgoKo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just to be clear, I've used the opamp symbol since we don't have amplifier symbol on circuit lab. Not that I'm aware of. But I'm depicting an amplifier with gain of G.

Ideally, the output \$z = G(x+y)\$. However, the amplifier have a gain error e. so the true output is \$z = (G+e)(x+y)\$.

Assuming that my amplifier has no offset error (just for this setup) and the only things I can measure are the input signal y and output signal z, I'm looking for a way to know the value of x.

What I'm looking at now is to input two values y1 and y2 to get z1 and z2. \$(z2-z1) = (G+e)(y2-y1)\$ so I'll get e. From y2, I get x.

Is there a simpler and more direct way to do this?

Comment: I've posted an answer, but deleted id, cause I undestand you maybe want to know maximum op-amp gain i open loop?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I'm using open loop gain to measure the unknown voltage x.

Comment: Unknown? So why it's 1V in your schematics?

Comment: Op-amp with same value at both inputs will give you always 0...

Comment: The circuit in this question makes no sense. VTC.

Comment: Sorry I've hurriedly made the circuit. If the circuit confuses you, I hope the equation will tell what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your diagram does not make much sense.

Based on the equation, change Y from 0 to 1V and measure the change in the output voltage.

Then you will have: \$ e + G = \frac{\Delta Z}{\Delta Y}\$ , provided Y stays constant.

If there is no offset then

\$X = \frac{Z}{e+G}\$ when Y = 0